# i have two input field where user can put their values, if the value vary so result should be changed

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have two input field where user can put their values, if the value vary so the amount should be changed. i do not know how to achieve it.

Please help i do not have enough knowledge of jquery

`<input type="text">` (black belt, blue belt, yellow belt)
`<input type="text">` (Quantity e.g.: 1,2,3,)
Result show here:

Comment: amount of what will change?

Comment: @reza if someone buy 1 product so the amount will be $1 if someone buy 3 product so the amount will be $3 or if someone buy 3-5 product so the amount will be $4  same how to achieve it

Comment: what i mean was what will be the relation with each input with the amount? if its only depends on only one input you can use jquery change functionality. and please share your code, so that we can help you. we are not going to write full code from scratch .

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle "change" event on those two input fields. like below

```js
$('#input1').change(function(){
calculateFinalAmount();
});
$('#input2').change(function(){
calculateFinalAmount();
});
function calculateFinalAmount()
{
var val1 = $('#input1').val();
  var val2 = $('#input1').val();
  
  //now calculate your final amount
  //and update whereever you are showing value.
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope to help. I personally use PHP along with MySQL. I recommend you learn PHP so that you have a good side-scripting tool continuously working with your input.

I would personally integrate your values to a running PHP server. For example, HTML would initiate the input and the PHP will adopt the values and will the change the result. This may seem complex at first - but PHP basics will really help with this so I recommend looking at some basic PHP.

Imagine you had

The PHP would have to request the results (pardon if I get the code not exactly as it should be - this will be a file called yourfileinphp.php!)

It's late here, and I haven't done pure PHP in some time, so expect errors from my work but just giving an insight to what I would personally do. Hope you find a good answer if mine wasn't sufficient. If it was please rate it!